# Powershell script to group multiple identical rows with different column

Tags: powershell, group-by

I have the below CSV exported from powershell
"objectGUID","sAMAccountName","givenName","SN","Description","mail","memberOf","preferredLanguage","manager","title","company","distinguishedName"

The only difference is MemberOf.
In AD a user is member of multiple AD groups and we want to export the user and his groups, the groups have to be exported in the same column not on different rows.

The code i wrote to get the output is

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Groups = import-csv CGroups.csv
Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{

$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group.identity | select name,samaccountname

foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
{
$user = Get-ADUser $member.samaccountname -properties mail,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,objectGuid,DisplayName,manager
$guid = $user.objectGuid
$immutableId = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($guid.ToByteArray())
$OBJNEW=IID2GUID $immutableId
$objatt15 = $OBJNEW.att15
$ADObj = Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionattribute15 -eq '$objatt15'" -Server dc.contoso.com:3268 -SearchBase 'dc=contoso,dc=net' -Properties msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress,extensionattribute8,mail,DisplayName,manager,title,company

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name objectGUID -Value $ADObj.objectGUID
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name sAMAccountName -Value $ADObj.sAMAccountName
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name givenName -Value $ADObj.givenName
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SN -Value $ADObj.Surname
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $ADObj.Description
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name mail -Value $ADObj.mail
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name memberOf -Value $Group.identity
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name preferredLanguage -Value $ADObj.preferredLanguage
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name manager -Value $ADObj.manager
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name title -Value $ADObj.title
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name company -Value $ADObj.company
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name distinguishedName -Value $ADObj.distinguishedName
$obj | export-csv -Append -NoTypeInformation CGroupExport.csv
}
}
```

Comment: You can combine the various groups a user is member of with a delimiter character. That way, you create a string from an array that will occupy just the one column. Use `-join ';'` on that property

Comment: You don't show your function IID2GUID, and I also do not understand why you would use `Get-ADUser` **twice** inside the loop. What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that so the initial Get-ADUser is from Source AD and we want to do match on a Target AD and we use IID2GUID to match by immutableid but this is not the request here. The goal is to get that memberof column in a string. My powershell coding skills stop at what you have seen up so if you can suggest the code for the -join that would be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the info about `IID2GUID`, so I won't bother with that.

Your code could be optimized by

1. capture the objects returned in a variable and save that to csv instead of appending to the csv in every iteration
2. You seem to ask for various user properties where they are never used and/or already returned by default by the various `Get-AD*` cmdlets
3. You're building each object 'old school' and by using `[PsCustomObject]@{..}` I think the readability of the code would improve

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\CGroups.csv'
# capture all output objects in a variable $result
$result = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    # Get-ADGroupMember can return objects of type group, user and computer
    # so we filter for users only. The objects returned already have an objectGUID property
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.identity | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' }

    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
        $guid        = $Member.objectGUID
        $immutableId = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($guid.ToByteArray())
        $OBJNEW      = IID2GUID $immutableId
        $objatt15    = $OBJNEW.att15

        # Get-ADUser by default returns these properties:
        # DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
        $adProps = 'Extensionattribute15','EmailAddress','DisplayName','Description','Manager','Title','Company','preferredLanguage'
        $ADObj   = Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionattribute15 -eq '$objatt15'" -Server 'dc.contoso.com:3268' -SearchBase 'dc=contoso,dc=net' -Properties $adProps
        if ($ADObj) {
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                objectGUID        = $ADObj.ObjectGUID
                sAMAccountName    = $ADObj.SamAccountName
                givenName         = $ADObj.GivenName
                SN                = $ADObj.Surname
                Description       = $ADObj.Description
                mail              = $ADObj.EmailAddress
                memberOf          = $Group.identity  # this will be grouped later
                preferredLanguage = $ADObj.preferredLanguage
                manager           = $ADObj.Manager
                title             = $ADObj.Title
                company           = $ADObj.Company
                distinguishedName = $ADObj.DistinguishedName
            }
        }
    }
}

# Now group the objects collected in $result on the `distinguishedName`
# property so we can combine the groups this user belongs to
$combined = $result | Group-Object distinguishedName | ForEach-Object {
    # output a new object for the user with the memberOf property combined
    $userGroups = $_.Group.memberOf -join '; '
    $_.Group[0] | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'memberOf'; Expression = {$userGroups}} -ExcludeProperty memberOf
}

# output the combined results in a CSV file
$combined | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\CGroupExport.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>The `Manager` property is the DistinguishedName of that manager user. If you want the Name instead, you can change that property into `manager = (Get-ADUser -Identity $ADObj.Manager).Name`</sup>

Comment: Hello Theo. Thank you very much for the very improved script. There is just a problem here . It seems the Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership doesn't work . I get this error "Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : The operation is not supported on Global Catalog port."

Comment: @Cristi I've been googling for this error and it seems `Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership` indeed has problems... [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2019-ps#description) suggests _"If you want to search for local groups in another domain, use the ResourceContextServer parameter to specify the alternate server in the other domain."_ but even with that a lot of people say that doesn't work for them..

Comment: @Cristi If you're cool with getting a set of DN's in the `memberOf` property of your output, you can add `MemberOf` to the `$adProps` array and set `$userGroups = $ADObj.MemberOf -join '; '`. If you need not the DN, but the group Name instead, you will need to loop through all of the groups returned and do `$userGroups = ($ADObj.MemberOf | ForEach-Object {(Get-ADGroup -Identity $_).Name} ) -join '; '`. (very time-consuming..)

Comment: Hello Theo. I've looked at what you suggested and it seems it returns all Groups that the user is a member of instead of listing just the ones i have in the initial List. My interest is to see if the user is a member of only those groups from $groups that i provide in the CSV file

Comment: @Cristi Oh, my bad. I have totally misread that it seems.. I have now updated my answer to combine the `memberOf` property afterwards